# Installing Caffe with CUDNN 8.0 and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2015, caffe

I'm a bit over my head here, so please try not to strangle me for all the mistakes I am making until the end :)

I am trying to install Caffe using a Windows 10 pc with VS 2015 and CUDNN 8.0.  I initially had trouble with the Microsoft supported Caffe files, so I found [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/Z8k0Tr3Ybww).  I couldn't figure out what to do with the first set of files, so I opened up the second set of files and used the official instructions to edit CommonSettings.props, installed the necessary packages, and hit build.

I got an error saying that OpenCV could not be found, even though it was definitely installed.  It seemed like it was looking for OpenCV in a place where it did not exist, so I copied the packages into the directory it was looking in.  I am now getting an error `cannot open file libboost_log-vc140-mt-1_59.lib`.  I've looked around and I can't find any file like that.  What many things am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check [windows branch](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) of official repository. I built it on win10 x64 machine using vs2015 and it works fine.